# How to override All Auth built-in templates Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-allauth

I am using Django all auth to implement password reset functionality but I want to customize the template of password reset,here's below my urls:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token,refresh_jwt_token
from . import views


# Registration,Login,Forgot,Profile change

urlpatterns=[

    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

]
```

and when I hit this url->http://127.0.0.1:8000/ThiefApp/accounts/password/reset/

I got below template

[image]

How can I customize the above template or how can I use different template.Any suggestions?

Comment: Use https://github.com/danihodovic/django-allauth-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

allauth contains many templates in allauth/templates directory. If you want to override any template then you need to add the template with the same name in your project that allauth template directory contains.(Ref : https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#overridable-templates).

Here you want to override password reset page then create a template of *"password_reset.html"* in your project. Your template directory structure must be like `yourproject/templates/allauth/account/`. I hope this will help you:)

Comment: Well I have created the template but still getting previous template,

Comment: @NabeelAyub update the template directory path as given in answer.

Comment: Thanks got it , can you please tell me also what is templates name to override accounts/password/reset/done/ , accounts/password/reset/key/4-set-password/ and ThiefApp/accounts/password/reset/key/done/.

Comment: You can find all templates in `allauth/account/` folder. Here you can easily get idea from template name which one to use.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get the same result but using an app directory instead of the project directory?

Answer (score 1):

I recently struggled with django-allauth 0.58.1, finally I've found out how it works (and it's really a beautifull piece of code, it would be a pitty to bypass that), so...

Just create templates paths that are similar to the ones of django-allauth, and put them in your main 'templates' DIR. You can find all the templates on [allauth's github](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/allauth/templates/)

A quick and easy customization could be :

- in the `templates/allauth/layouts/base.html` redirect to your own base.html (or use it as your own base):

```
{% extends 'my_base.html' %}
```

- be sure `{% load socialaccount %}`is at the top of your own base.html
- Customize all the elements in **templates/allauth/elements/** (faster than it seems)

In [allauth's github examples](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/main/example/example/templates) you'll find some prepared templates, I strongly recommend to copy/paste (and then customize) at least this 2:

- allauth/elements/fields.html
- allauth/elements/field.html

That should be helpfull for more than myself, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, I hope this will work for you:

```
yourproject/templates/account/

yourproject/templates/openid/

yourproject/templates/socialaccount/
```